# How do I add a dropdown field containing foreign keys in Symfony?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm coding with PHP/Symfony, where I have a Budget and Income relationship.

The Income entity contains an id (integer), name (string), amount (integer) and a foreign key (pointing to the Budget entity):

```
// Income.php

#[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: 'Budget', inversedBy: 'incomes')]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'budget_id', referencedColumnName: 'id', nullable: 'false')]
private $budget;

...

/**
* @param mixed $budget
*/
public function setBudget(Budget $budget): void
{
  $budget->addIncome($this);
  $this->budget = $budget;
}
```

I have created a fully working form using `FormBuilderInterface` with two fields (name and amount). I'm able to save and edit the created data.

My question is how do I add a foregin key dropdown field to the form (see code below) which contains the data from the Budget entity? So for example if I have created two budgets "2021" and "2022" then I would like to have those two appear in the dropdown field. I have tried the solution below, but then I get this error message: `Can't get a way to read the property "budget" in class "App\Entity\Income"`

```
class IncomeFormType extends AbstractType
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
  {
    $builder
      ->add('name')
      ->add('description')
      ->add('amount')
      ->add('budget', ChoiceType::class, ['choice_filter' => 'isSelectable'])
    ;
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the EntityType https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Entity form class instead of Choice one:

```
class IncomeFormType extends AbstractType
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
  {
    $builder
      ->add('name')
      ->add('description')
      ->add('amount')
      ->add('budget', EntityType::class, [
        'class' => Budget::class,
        'choice_filter' => 'isSelectable',
      ])
    ;
  }
```

If you need to use some field to represent your entity in the list you should add `choice_label` option to the field relating to corresponding field in Budget class.

Also consider to use `query_builder` option to filter list of appropriate entities instead of using `choice_filter`. It will reduce memory usage and will improve performance of your app. Example of query_builder:

```
'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
    return $er->createQueryBuilder('b')
        ->where('b.isSelectable = true') // if it is just field in DB or you can use any condition here
        ->orderBy('b.name', 'ASC'); // also help you ordering your entities in right order
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I see that now. However, the same error still shows up. What could cause it? This is the error: ´Can't get a way to read the property "budget" in class "App\Entity\Income"´

Comment: @FreePalestine Is there any getter method for this field?

Comment: That did the trick! Missed the getter method. Thanks for the help, really appreciate it! Right now the default value of the foreign key dropdown is the first object. Is there a way of making it blank instead (when loading the form)?

Comment: @FreePalestine, you can use `placeholder` option on form to do that